# HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed no metodo @DELETE

Tags: banco-de-dados, web-service, java-ee, rest

Eu criei um webservice que acessa um banco de dados MySQL, mas não consigo deletar registros, recebo sempre o seguinte retorno:

**HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed**.
The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.

Quando executo a mesma query no console do banco, o registro é deletado. Vi diversos tutoriais utilizando o método @DELETE da mesma forma, não consigo encontrar a razão.

Esse é o código do meu WS:

```
package ws;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import dao.PokemonDAO;
import dao.TrainerDAO;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import model.Pokemon;
import model.Trainer;


@Path("pokews")
public class PokedexWebService {

PokemonDAO pokemonDAO = new PokemonDAO();
TrainerDAO trainerDAO = new TrainerDAO();

@Context
private UriInfo context;

public PokedexWebService() {
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String getXml() {
    //TODO return proper representation object
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("poke/list")
public ArrayList<Pokemon> pokeList() {
    return pokemonDAO.listPokemon();
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("poke/fetch/{id}")
public Pokemon pokeFetch(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    return pokemonDAO.fetchPokemon(id);
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("poke/isFavorite/{id}")
public String pokeIsFavorite(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    return pokemonDAO.isFavorite(id);
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("poke/{login}/{pwd}")
public Trainer pokelogin(@PathParam("login") String login, @PathParam("pwd") String pwd) {
    return trainerDAO.authUser(login, pwd);
}

@DELETE
@Path("poke/delete/{id}")
public boolean delete(@PathParam("id")int id) {
    return pokemonDAO.deletePokemon(id);
}

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("poke/insert")
public boolean pokeInsert(String content) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Pokemon pokemon = (Pokemon) gson.fromJson(content, Pokemon.class);
    return pokemonDAO.insertPokemon(pokemon);
}

@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("poke/update")
public boolean pokeUpdate(String content) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Pokemon pokemon = (Pokemon) gson.fromJson(content, Pokemon.class);
    return pokemonDAO.updatePokemon(pokemon);
}


@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public void putXml(String content) {
}


}
```

Este é o código do meu DAO:

```
    package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import dbconn.ConnectionFactory;
import model.Pokemon;

public class PokemonDAO {

    public boolean insertPokemon(Pokemon pokemon) {

        try {
            Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();

            String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `pokedex`.`pokemon` (`name`,`species`,`weight`,`height`,`image`,`isFavorite`,`trainerId`) "
                                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 0, ?)";

            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
            stmt.setString(1, pokemon.getName());
            stmt.setString(2, pokemon.getSpecies());
            stmt.setString(3, pokemon.getWeight());
            stmt.setString(4, pokemon.getHeight());
            stmt.setString(5, pokemon.getImage());
                        stmt.setInt(6, pokemon.getTrainerId());

            stmt.executeUpdate();
                        stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    public boolean deletePokemon(int id) {      

        try {
            Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();

            String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM `pokedex`.`pokemon` WHERE id = ?;";

            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(deleteQuery);
            stmt.setInt(1
                                , id);

            stmt.executeUpdate();
                        stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;    
    }


    public ArrayList<Pokemon> listPokemon() {
        ArrayList<Pokemon> pokemonList = new ArrayList<Pokemon>();

        try {
            Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();

            //String listQuery = "SELECT * fROM `pokedex`.`pokemon`";
            String listQuery = "SELECT `pokemon`.`id`,\n" +
                                            "    `pokemon`.`name`,\n" +
                                            "    `pokemon`.`species`,\n" +
                                            "    `pokemon`.`weight`,\n" +
"    `pokemon`.`height`,\n" +
"    `pokemon`.`image`,\n" +
"    `pokemon`.`isFavorite`,\n" +
"    `pokemon`.`trainerId`\n" +
"FROM `pokedex`.`pokemon`;";

            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(listQuery);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()) {
                Pokemon pokemon = new Pokemon();

                pokemon.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                pokemon.setName(rs.getString(2));
                pokemon.setSpecies(rs.getString(3));
                pokemon.setWeight(rs.getString(4));
                pokemon.setHeight(rs.getString(5));
                pokemon.setImage(rs.getString(6));
                pokemon.setIsFavorite(rs.getString(7));
                pokemon.setTrainerId(rs.getInt(8));

                pokemonList.add(pokemon);
            }

            rs.close();
                        stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return pokemonList;
    }

    public Pokemon fetchPokemon(int id) {
        Pokemon pokemon = null;

        try {
            Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();


            String fetchQuery = "SELECT * fROM `pokedex`.`pokemon` WHERE id = ?;";

            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(fetchQuery);
            stmt.setInt(1, id);

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()) {
                pokemon = new Pokemon();
                pokemon.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                pokemon.setName(rs.getString(2));
                pokemon.setSpecies(rs.getString(3));
                pokemon.setWeight(rs.getString(4));
                pokemon.setHeight(rs.getString(5));
                pokemon.setImage(rs.getString(6));
                pokemon.setIsFavorite(rs.getString(7));
                pokemon.setTrainerId(rs.getInt(8));
            } else {
                return pokemon;
            }

            rs.close();
                        stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return pokemon;
    }

    public boolean updatePokemon(Pokemon pokemon) {

        try {
            Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();

            String insertQuery = "UPDATE `pokedex`.`pokemon` SET `name` = ?, `species` = ?, `weight` = ?, "
                                + "`height` = ?, `image` = ?, `isFavorite` = ? WHERE `id` = ?;";



            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
            stmt.setString(1, pokemon.getName());
            stmt.setString(2, pokemon.getSpecies());
            stmt.setString(3, pokemon.getWeight());
            stmt.setString(4, pokemon.getHeight());
            stmt.setString(5, pokemon.getImage());
                        stmt.setString(5, pokemon.isFavorite());
            stmt.setInt(6, pokemon.getId());

            stmt.executeUpdate();
                        stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

        public String isFavorite(int id) {
        Pokemon pokemon = null;

        try {
            Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();


            String fetchQuery = "SELECT teste fROM `pokedex`.`pokemon` WHERE id = ?;";

            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(fetchQuery);
            stmt.setInt(1, id);

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()) {
                pokemon = new Pokemon();
                pokemon.setIsFavorite(rs.getString(1));
            } else {
                return pokemon.isFavorite();
            }

            rs.close();
                        stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return pokemon.isFavorite();
        }

        return pokemon.isFavorite();
    }
}
```

Este é o código que eu usei para chamar o serviço:

```
package acessorest;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect.Type;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


public class HttpExemplo {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpExemplo http = new HttpExemplo();
        Gson gson = new Gson();  
                Pokemon pokemon = new Pokemon();
                java.lang.reflect.Type pokemonType = new TypeToken<Pokemon>() {
                }.getType();

                String chamadaWS = "http://localhost:8081/PokedexWS/webresources/pokews/poke/delete/1";
                String retorno = http.sendGet(chamadaWS, "DELETE");
                //pokemon = gson.fromJson(json, pokemonType);
                System.out.println(retorno);



    }

    // HTTP GET request
    private String sendGet(String url, String method) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

                return response.toString();

    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost(String url, String parameters, String method) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

[image: Mas continuo recebendo o mesmo erro]

Comment: Consegue postar  o código que está fazendo a requisição?

Comment: Eu não fiz código para a requisição, estou testando pelo netbeans, vou em "Testar webservices restful" e rodo o teste no browser. Pretendo chamar o webservice pelo android posteriormente

Comment: Faz um teste utilizando o POSTMAN mandando uma requisição do tipo Delete para o teu Webservice. Pelo Browser eu estou achando q ele está tentando dar um GET.

Comment: Eu adicionei o código completo do meu WS e da minha DAO. Também coloquei o código que estou usando para testar a chamada do WS e o retorno que estou recebendo. Ainda é 405.

Answer (score 1):

Eu testei com o Postman e deu certo[image]] Provavelmente, o Netbeans estava tentando estava fazendo a requisição como se fosse um GET mesmo.
Depois eu vi o erro que cometi no código que estava fazendo a request. Estava passando a função "DELETE" como parâmetro, mas não estava pegando este parâmetro no código. Peguei ele na internet e já estava setado com o GET como default e eu não me atentei a mudar isso. Abaixo, o código correto da requisição:

```
package acessorest;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect.Type;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


public class HttpExemplo {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpExemplo http = new HttpExemplo();
        Gson gson = new Gson();  
                Pokemon pokemon = new Pokemon();
                java.lang.reflect.Type pokemonType = new TypeToken<Pokemon>() {
                }.getType();

                String chamadaWS = "http://localhost:8081/PokedexWS/webresources/pokews/poke/delete/3";
                String retorno = http.sendGet(chamadaWS, "DELETE");
                //pokemon = gson.fromJson(json, pokemonType);
                System.out.println(retorno);



    }

    // HTTP GET request
    private String sendGet(String url, String method) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod(method);

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

                return response.toString();

    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost(String url, String parameters, String method) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

Estou postando o retorno que obtive no console também:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]